# Elasticsearch distinct multi search result

Tags: elasticsearch

I use Elasticsearch 2.2 and when using Multi Search API, it's possible to distinct the result between the first search and the second search??
I have multi search query dsl like this

```
{}
{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"terms": {"mtart": ["roh"]}},{"terms": {"werks": ["f230","f232"]}}]}},"query": {"query_string": {"query": "roh"}}}}}
{}
{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"mtart":["roh","nlag"]}},{"terms":{"werks":["f230","f231"]}}]}},"query":{"query_string":{"query":"roh"}}}}}
```

The result for the first search is 12 hits and the second is 39 hits. But there is duplicate value between first search and second search. And I want to distinct all the hits and get the unique documents. It is possible to do it??

Thanks a lot

Comment: How are you accessing API, any library?

Comment: Yes, there is java API for multi search. look at this --> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-msearch.html